# Em C++ qual o comando correspondente ao super() do Java?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Em Java:

```
public class Teste extends Testando
{
    private String nome;
    private int numero;
    public Teste(String teste, String nome, int numero)
    {
        super(teste);
        this.nome = nome;
        this.numero = numero;
    }
}
```

Qual é comando correspondente ao `super()` em `C++`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você chama explicitamente pelo nome da classe, até porque em C++ há herança múltipla e pode ter mais de um ancestral. A grosso modo seria isto:

```
class Teste : public Testando {
    String nome;
    int numero;
    public:
        Teste(String teste, String nome, int numero) : Testando(teste) {      
            this.nome = nome;
            this.numero = numero;
        }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/OOP/Super.cpp).

Comment: Estava escrevendo uma resposta que era o segundo exemplo, mas já que o fez +1

Comment: Acho que a segunda me parece mais "organizada" e até mais comum, não sei como esta o padrão no C++11 e 14, se é que existe algum padrão, eu pessoalmente divido os .hpp e os .cpp e faço a chamada do "super" no .cpp, mas claro que isso é como eu faço, ao que pesquisei a pouco (infelizmente links antigos) não encontrei nenhum padrão definitivo, então ambos exemplos me parecem bons (apesar de preferir o segundo).

Comment: Acho que na primeira pode ser também sem o nome da classe, por exemplo: `::Testando(teste)`. Não?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu prefiro o segundo, coloquei o primeiro para ficar parecido com o que ele fez. Eu me lembro de alguma coisa que se torna problemático quando faz o primeiro, mas não lembro o que. Eu pouco usei C++, nunca estudei a fundo. Arrumei conforme o LuizVieira falou.

Comment: Tenho impressão que o primeiro exemplo está errado: está chamando o construtor da classe base e criando um temporário, que é descartado...provavelmente o compilador deve avisar. O segundo modo é a maneira correta de chamar o construtor de uma classe base.

Answer (score 2):

Não há uma relação direta em C++.

É possível fazer algo similar se você criar um typedef super para todas as classes que quiser usar esse recurso, como no caso abaixo:

```
class Derivada: public Base
{
   private:
      typedef Base super; // não deve ser público porque cada classe pode 
                          // ter apenas uma classe super
} ;
```

E então você poderia usar super no lugar do nome da classe base, como no exemplo:

```
super::meumetodo();
```

Porém, não é recomendável abusar deste recurso. Em C++ existe a possibilidade de herança múltipla e isso já complicaria a solução, podendo causar confusão.

Comment: E se tiver herança múltipla?

Comment: Não vai funcionar, claro. Por isso comentei que geraria confusão... mesmo que você escolha uma das classes para ser a super e a outra considere interface...

Comment: É verdade, na correria nem vi :)