# Como passar o classe (Teste2 teste2) como referencia no ("super") construtor do C++?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, operadores, herança, construtor

Com base nessa resposta [Em C++ qual o comando correspondente a super() do Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120162/em-c-qual-o-comando-correspondente-a-super-do-java)

```
Class Teste2{
int x;
int y;
public:
  Teste2(int x, int y){
.
.
.
}
}
class Testando{
 Teste2 *teste2;
public:
   Testando(Teste *teste2)
{.
 .
 .
 .
class Teste : public Testando {
    string nome;
    int numero;
    public:
         //Supondo que Teste2 teste2 foi instanciado na Classe Testando
        Teste(Teste2 *teste2, string nome, int numero) : Testando(teste2) {      
            this.nome = nome;
            this.numero = numero;
```

Como passar por referência uma classe no construtor ?

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer, nem o objetivo, principalmente, mas não só, porque falta contexto.

Comment: @bigown na outra pergunta era uma `string`  agora uma classe ou tipo Test2, ficou claro ou não?

Comment: É difícil te ajudar porque apensar de você dizer que vai mudar, sempre coloca códigos tudo pela metade, sem contexto, sem organização, a gente fica perdido sem saber sequer o que o código deveria fazer e ter que ficar completando, arrumando, até o código compilar. Já leu isto? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve O código deve ser compilável pelo menos na parte que não faz parte da dúvida. Jogar código de qualquer jeito dificulta qualquer ajuda.

Comment: @bigown entendo, que esse código crie na hora aqui no site não tenho pronto, mas acredito que seja as bibliotecas que estão faltando. `#include<Teste2>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código tem diversos pequenos problemas, eu nem sei o que dizer para esclarecer a dúvida da pergunta porque não a entendi, nem sei se tem um dúvida específica mesmo. Havia um código jogado sem muito critério e que sequer dava pra testar. Note que eu não mudei nada para fazer funcionar o que foi perguntado, fui arrumando erros básicos de sintaxe e o que mais poderia ser uma dúvida é a mudança do operador `.` para o operador `->` no `this`.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Teste2 {
    int x;
    int y;
    public:
        Teste2(int x, int y) {}
};
class Testando {
    Teste2 *teste2;
    public:
        Testando(Teste2 *teste2) {}
};
class Teste : public Testando {
    string nome;
    int numero;
    public:
         //Supondo que Teste2 teste2 foi instanciado na Classe Testando
        Teste(Teste2 *teste2, string nome, int numero) : Testando(teste2) {      
            this->nome = nome;
            this->numero = numero;
        }
};
int main() {
    auto teste = Teste(new Teste2(1, 2), "joão", 1);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/82QaaV). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tgztrnbn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/OOP/ConstructorInheritance.cpp).

Pra falar a verdade acho que a maioria desses códigos não fazem sentido e não acredito que isto está ensinando alguma coisa realmente útil.

Comment: minha dúvida era nesse trecho do código `  Teste(Teste2 *teste2, string nome, int numero) : Testando(teste2) { ` o jeito que coloquei estava correto?

Comment: Sim, só não sei se realmente precisa isto, mas como eu digo código soltos sem contexto qualquer coisa que compila está certa.